# Enable S3 bucket contents to always be public

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, s3fs

I've managed to use S3FS to mount an Amazon S3 folder into my Wordpress site. Basically, my gallery folder for NextGEN gallery is a symlink to a mounted S3FS folder of the bucket, so when I upload an image, the file is automatically added to the S3 bucket.

I'm busy writing an Apache rewrite rule to replace the links, to fetch gallery images from S3 instead, without having to hack or change anything with NextGEN, but one problem I'm finding, is that images are not public by default on S3.

Is there a way to change a parent folder, to make its children always be public, including new files as they are generated?

Is it possible or advisable to use a cron task to manually make a folder public using the S3 command line API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded s3curl and used that to add the bucket policy to S3.

See this link: http://blog.travelmarx.com/2012/09/working-with-s3curl-and-amazon-s3.html

You can generate your bucket policies using the Amazon Policy Generator:

http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm the lead developer and maintainer of Open source project [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs): a userspace filesystem to mount Amazon S3 buckets.

Our project is an alternative to “s3fs” project, main advantage comparing to “s3fs” are: simplicity, the speed of operations and bugs-free code. Currently [the project](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) is in the “beta” state, but it's been running on several high-loaded fileservers for quite some time.

We are seeking for more people to join our project and help with the testing. From our side we offer quick bugs fix and will listen to your requests to add new features.

Regarding your issue:

if'd you use [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs), you could mount a bucket and have a write / read access to it using the following command (assuming you have installed [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) and have exported AWSACCESSKEYID and AWSSECRETACCESSKEY environment variables):

```
riofs  -o allow_other http://s3.amazonaws.com bucket_name /mnt/static.example.com
```

(please refer to project description for command line arguments)

Please note that the project is still in the development, there are could be still a number of bugs left.

If you find that something doesn't work as expected: please fill a issue report on the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs/issues?state=open).

Hope it helps and we are looking forward to seeing you joined our community !

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already setup S3FS unfortunately. My folder is read/write enabled, but not allowed for public access, for that you need to set a bucket policy. I managed to solve this by using s3curl. ;)